# If specific player joins VoiceServer

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I create a DiscordBot and I would like to play a sound, when a specific User joins a VoiceChannel. Like I join and my Bot plays "Hello.mp3" and when Bob join my Bot plays "John.mp3". 
I know I need a if clauses, but what next? 
And how can i check if the user id from VoiceConnect equals "19923Example"?

Your 
SchinkTasia

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kinldy provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to **[voiceStateUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate)**, this will notify the bot for when someone joined/left a voice channel. You'll get a `oldMember` and a `newMember`.

`oldMember` its the GuildMember **before** he joined the voice channel.
`newMember` its the GuildMember **after** he joined the voice channel.

So what you need to do is check what voice channel `newMember` joined (`newMember.voiceChannelID`) and check if thats the voice channel you want.

Then you'll need to check what member that was. `newMember.user.id` if you checking for IDs or `newMember.user.tag` if you are checking for the tag `Test#1234`.

If you don't have a database, or its for just a couple members, you could use a object to save each member id and the music to play.

```
var musics = { "123": "music1.mp3", "321": "music2.mp3"};
```

Then if everything matches you can join the newMember voice channel and play the song:

```
newMember.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
  const dispatcher = connection.playFile('path/to/'+musics[newMember.user.id]);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit late, but thank you  I tryed it in a similar way and it worked, in the past